# Rails: User has_many CityPreferences model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

Let's say a "user" wants to specify their favorite "cities". What is the correct way to model this relationship?

**Option 1**

Associations:

```
User has_many :cities through :city_preferences. 
CityPreferences belongs_to :user and :city. 
City has_many :users through :city_prefences.
```

Tables:

```
User
email:string, first_name:string, last_name:string

CityPreferences
user:references, city:references

City
name:string
```

**Option 2**

Associations:

```
User has_many :city_preferences
CityPreferences belongs_to :user
```

Tables:

```
User 
email:string, first_name:string, last_name:string

CityPreferences
user:references city:string
```

Comment: Have a look at `has_many...through` association: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve that with the help of the `has_many :sm, through: :relation`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_city_relations
  has_many :preferred_cities, through: :user_city_relations, source: :city

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_city_relations
  has_many :users, through: :user_city_relations

class UserCityRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
  validates :user_id, :city_id, presence: true
```

And use it like this:

```
user.preferred_cities
```

---

It is very similar to a `has_and_belongs_to_many` but here you define the join model by yourself, which gives you more control about this relation. It is also more flexible (for new features in the futures, like active/inactive preferred Cities, etc.)

Comment: interesting, thank you! Why the usage of `class_name: :city` instead of just calling the `City` table `PreferredCity`?

Comment: You might want to use the City model as a regular City, since it actually represent a City object. You can do as you say, but then if later you want to use this model, it's name would be irrelevant IMO --- I got an example for you: in 2 months, your manager asks you to add a feature on your app where the User can choose from which City he comes from. It would be very easy to add: `belongs_to :living_city, class_name: 'City'`

Comment: would you then add a column to UserCityRelation saying what the relation is?

Comment: That could be a solution. But in my opinion just a `belongs_to :living_city, class_name: 'City'` would be sufficient and require less  work from you and probably use less resources on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're not asking *how* to implement option 1 or 2, but which of option 1 or option 2 is preferred.

That depends on your application and whether you want each city to exist and be managed as a separate object.